# How to use dex2jar project?

Tags: java, android, jar, dex2jar

I have been looking for dex2jar.jar file since i have used it once few months ago, but since the project has changed a lot, I cannot find the jar anywhere on Internet, the project i have found out is:

https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

and only thing that i can see in this project are so many build.gradles, and the bonus is that there is no documentation and how tos on project page, If i want to get a jar file out of an apk, do i have to sit for hours and get a jar file out of all these small projects or there is a better way to do it, i am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Its using maven, try issuing `mvn package` in the root of project folder.

Comment: First of all thnx fr replying, can u please elaborate it further...?

Comment: The project is using [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) to manage dependencies, You can use it to build a JAR file too. You will need to install Maven on ubuntu `sudo apt-get install maven`. After navigating to the project root where the pom.xml is located issue the above command. It should create a JAR file under the target/ directory.

Comment: It looks like a muti module project, so it will create JAR's for each module within moduleName/target folders..

Comment: @AngadSingh, you don't have to build the project. You should be clicking on the "Releases" tab on the github repo's page. Use this [link](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases) to download dex2jar.
Edit: I know this question is very old, but posting this comment just so that people visiting this thread will have an answer.